# Importing animated 3D models in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8, maya, javafx-3d

I am currently working on creating a 3D scene using JavaFX. In the scene I would like to show some more complex 3D models. I, therefore, used the InteractiveMesh importers for importing some OBJ/STL models, which worked fine. I would also like to include an animated model (walk cycle). I found the JavaFX sample application 3DViewer which includes a Maya-Importer. As I am not that familiar with Maya and 3D modelling in general I tried to find some free models, which are animated or at least rigged, online. Unfortunately, I could not find a single model, neither suitable for creating an animated walk cycle (rigged) nor already animated, I could successfully open in 3DViewer. The import usually fails due to Nullpointer- or IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions while loading the Maya model.

I am now wondering if somebody has already managed to open an animated Maya model in 3DViewer? I highly appreciate references to models, which can successfully be imported.

Additionally, are there other ways of importing animated 3D models (not necessarily Maya models) into JavaFX?

Comment: FYI the Duke maya files for the chess demo have been [released](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/duke/duke/file/e71b60779736/3D) recently, and you can use [3D Viewer](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/tree/develop/apps/samples/3DViewer) to open them and play the animations.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at this project: https://github.com/jperedadnr/RiggedHand

It is not exactly doing what you want (import an animated 3D model), but it manages to animate a given 3D model, in this case using Leap Motion.

You can have a look at the result on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_xiv1pV3tI).

If you check [HandImporter](https://github.com/jperedadnr/RiggedHand/blob/master/src/riggedhand/HandImporter.java) class, it is based in the creation of a `SkinningMesh`, as it is defined under the 3DViewer project you already mentioned. This will contain the 3D mesh for the hand, the weights and the tree of joints.

[image: RiggedHand]

This is the same technic as the one used for the Duke chess [animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJe-_3nZkns):

[image: RiggedDuke]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I really like your RiggedHand-project - great work. I'll check if I can use your ideas for animating my walking character. I would have really liked to use the maya importer for importing full animations though as this appeared to be a rather simple approach. Thanks again.

Comment: Importers found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fxyz3d/fxyz3d-importers/

Comment: Yes, @Terran, we have recently added to FXyz the .OBJ and .MA (Maya) importers from the 3DViewer project. You can actually play the Duke chess animation above if you run the FXyz [Sampler](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz#fxsampler)

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally, are there other ways of importing animated 3D models (not necessarily Maya models) into JavaFX?

and the bounty's

> I would like to see a solution for importing any readied animated 3D model into JavaFX.

It appears that the [3D viewer](https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/tree/master/apps/samples/3DViewer)'s support for `.ma` files is the only readily available way to import 3D animated models.

[InteractiveMesh's importers](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html) do not import animation, as well as [Tesis Dynaware's FBX importer](https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/fbx-importer).

**Edit:**

[OpenJDK](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/3D+Features) lists that it will not provide importers:

> Loader support
>
> - Many 3D file formats exist, such as:
>
>   - Obj, Maya, 3D Studio Max, Collada, KRML
> - We will not provide a loader as part of the JavaFX runtime
> - We will make sample code available for one or two popular formats

See the comments there as well as this [enhancement request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091851).

Comment: @Mark Something like that. A lot of searching and asking a few people (like the FBX importer writer). Unfortunately there are no plans to provide importers/loaders - see my edit.