# Vertex Skinning/Triangle Animation in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, vertex

I'm currently working on an Importer for the glTF into JavaFX.

Currently I'm working on the animations and hit the "Vertex Skinning". Because JavaFX already has a animation Framework I'd expect there to be a way to use Vertex skinning / a skin / a way to animate triangle meshes or similar but no matter how I search I can't find anything about that.

So is there a way to animate triangle meshes / skins in JavaFX ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `AnimationTimer`?

Comment: @Slaw well that entirely depends. Technically I only need the Animations already there to move Nodes around and if there's a way to do vertex skinning in FX the triangle mesh is supposed to change shape. If it is not yet implemented well than the animation timer will be a nessesary. You may want to take a look at :https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_020_Skins.md

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660031/3956070)? Also, FXyz3D has [importers](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/tree/master/FXyz-Importers/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/importers) of animated Maya models. Try the Maya sample in the FXyz Sampler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX has no built-in concept to animate a triangle mesh. But nothing keeps you from manipulating the geometry of the mesh at runtime yourself. If you can compute the necessary changes of the geometry you can use an AnimationTimer to drive that process.